# order items by parent and child in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of data in angular.

```
0: {id: 7, name: "333", code: "333", type: 3, hasParent: true, parentId: 4}

1: {id: 6, name: "dfgdfg", code: "dfgdfg", type: 3, hasParent: false, parentId: null}

2: {id: 5, name: "111", code: "111", type: 3, hasParent: true, parentId: 4}

3: {id: 4, name: "22", code: "22", type: 1, hasParent: false, parentId: null}

4: {id: 3, name: "yyy", code: "yyyy", type: 2, hasParent: false, parentId: null}

5: {id: 2, name: "dfgdfg", code: "dfgdfg", type: 3, hasParent: true, parentId: 1}

6: {id: 1, name: "cbcvb", code: "cvbcvcbv", type: 2, hasParent: false, parentId: null}
```

I need to order this list by parent and child in the angular material table.

my scenario is this :

**If the parent value of the item is equal to the value of the id of another item, the item that has the value of the parentId should be placed under the item whose parent value is equal to id value.**

that items must sort by this :

```
4: {id: 3, name: "yyy", code: "yyyy", type: 2, hasParent: false, parentId: 6}

1: {id: 6, name: "dfgdfg", code: "dfgdfg", type: 3, hasParent: false, parentId: null}

0: {id: 7, name: "333", code: "333", type: 3, hasParent: true, parentId: 4}

2: {id: 5, name: "111", code: "111", type: 3, hasParent: true, parentId: 4}

3: {id: 4, name: "22", code: "22", type: 1, hasParent: false, parentId: null}

5: {id: 2, name: "dfgdfg", code: "dfgdfg", type: 3, hasParent: true, parentId: 1}

6: {id: 1, name: "cbcvb", code: "cvbcvcbv", type: 2, hasParent: false, parentId: null}
```

**how can I solve this problem ????**

Comment: How did you try to accomplish this?

Comment: @AluanHaddad i dont have any idea for doing this

Comment: Then you need to learn programming fundamentals before even _considering_ using a complex framework like angular. I would write a few console apps to learn the basics

Comment: What about parentId: null ? How they are ordered?

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank  you for your guid but i know about the programning in angular  . i think you dont understand my question . this is complex and i need more guide for solve that

Comment: @VimalMunjani when the `parentId:null` mean that item is the main and that maybe have a child

Comment: That may well be true, but you are supposed to include an attempted solution. All you have done is show some data. I'd be happy to help, but not without an attempt

Comment: Also, `4: {id: 3, name: "yyy", code: "yyyy", type: 2, hasParent: false, parentId: 6}`. This is wrong I think, it says hasParent: false and still has a parentId

Comment: @VimalMunjani i change that data manuel just for this question in staoverflow editor

Comment: @kianoushdortaj How to know, which rows are gonna be child of someone that has parentId: null?

Comment: @VimalMunjani by parentId . when parentId equal by id that mean it child of that item

Comment: @kianoushdortaj And what about the childs that have Ids which does not have a corresponding parentId?

Comment: @VimalMunjani maybe one parent have 10 child or maybe have 0

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var Data = [{ id: 7, name: "333", code: "333", type: 3, hasParent: true, parentId: 4 },
{ id: 6, name: "dfgdfg", code: "dfgdfg", type: 3, hasParent: false, parentId: null },
{ id: 5, name: "111", code: "111", type: 3, hasParent: true, parentId: 4 },
{ id: 4, name: "22", code: "22", type: 1, hasParent: false, parentId: null },
{ id: 3, name: "yyy", code: "yyyy", type: 2, hasParent: false, parentId: null },
{ id: 2, name: "dfgdfg", code: "dfgdfg", type: 3, hasParent: true, parentId: 1 },
{ id: 1, name: "cbcvb", code: "cvbcvcbv", type: 2, hasParent: false, parentId: null }];


var result = [];
Data.forEach((values) => {
    if (result.indexOf(values) === -1) {
        result.push(values);
    }
    if (values.parentId !== null) {
        var d_ = Data.filter(srch => {
            return values.parentId === srch.id;
        });
        if (result.indexOf(d_[0]) === -1) {
            result.push(d_[0]);
        }
    }
});
console.log(result);
```